# Is there a way to overwrite or remove blueprintjs custom styles for global elements like <ul>?

Tags: css, blueprintjs

Most of the style classes from Blueprintjs is prefixed with .pt- so it doesn't bleed into global CSS but there's a handful of custom styles for elements like `<ul>, <pre>, <li>` where the custom styles are set on the element itself and so bleeds into global CSS.  Is there anyway around this? To remove all custom styles set on elements?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around this, short of compiling your own CSS file and excluding those Sass files that generate global selectors (*strongly not recommended*).

There is an issue for this on the GitHub where you can follow the discussion: https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/244